# How to find first cell of table rows with querySelectorAll()

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to target a table by its data attribute value. I would then like to find the first `<td>` of every `<tr>` in that table, and add a class to each `<td>` that is selected.

I attempted the following, however I am stuck in understanding the source of my error:

```
var mprimary = document.querySelectorAll("[data='regMultipleTable']");
for (var i = 0; i < mprimary.rows.length; i++) {
   var firstTD = mprimary.rows[i].cells[0];
   firstTD.className = 'your-the-first';
}
```

My table looks like this:

```
<table data="regMultipleTable">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
<tr>
<td>7</td>
<td>8</td>
<td>9</td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I want to target the td with values 1, 4, 7, etc...
Please help

Comment: Use `querySelector`, not `querySelectorAll`

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("table[data='regMultipleTable'] td:first-child")`

Comment: As an aside, it should be `you're-the-first`... though you probably don't want to go to the extent of escaping the apostrophe.

Comment: @ObsidianAge, hehe yes!  I would rather misspell  the word in this case :)

Comment: @Barmar thank you! you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simplify your logic by using the following selector:

```
table[data='regMultipleTable'] td:first-child
```

This selector means, "select the first td of every parent (row) in the table with data attribute of 'regMultipleTable'".

In code, this could look like:

```js
var mprimary = document
.querySelectorAll("table[data='regMultipleTable'] td:first-child");

for (var node of mprimary) {
  
  node.classList.add("your-the-first");
}
```

```css
.your-the-first {
  background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<table data="regMultipleTable">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The `tr` in the query is not needed since you are using spaces (descendants).

Answer (score 2):

`querySelectorAll()` returns a list of all the tables with that `data` attribute.

If there can be multiple such tables, you need to loop over them.

```
var mprimary = document.querySelectorAll("[data='regMultipleTable']");
mprimary.forEach(function(mprimary) {
  for (var i = 0; i < mprimary.rows.length; i++) {
    var firstTD = mprimary.rows[i].cells[0];
    firstTD.className = 'your-the-first';
  }
});
```

If there should only be one table, just use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`. It returns that single element instead of a list.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing with the class is styling [`border`, `background`, `width`, or `visibility`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns), you can put a [`<col>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col) element in the table and apply the class to that:

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table data="regMultipleTable">
  <col class="highlight">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>9</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you have a jquery in your project, you can do with one line

```
$("table[data='regMultipleTable'] tr td:first").addClass("your-the-first")
```

after @charlietfl comment;

```
$("table[data='regMultipleTable']").find("tr").find("td:first").addClass("your-the-first")
```

is better.

Comment: This only returns first `td` in table, not each row https://jsfiddle.net/9vjodrwy/